# Get errors when exporting data to CSV files in Qt

Tags: qt, csv

I am writing a small application to export data to CSV files. And this is the code that I used

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(
    this,
    tr("Save As"),
    "",
    tr("Comma Separated Values (*.csv);;All Files (*.*)"));

if (fileName.isEmpty()) return;
else {
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Unable to open file"), file.errorString());
        return;
    }

    // Write content to *.csv file
    QTextStream stream(&file);

    // Print header
    stream << "ID\tUsername\tAddress";

    stream.flush();
    file.close();
}
```

Then I run the application, a dialog appears to save CSV file. But when I open the CSV file that I have just saved, I got 2 following error warnings

[image: Cannot export CSV file]

and

[image: Cannot export CSV file]

This is the data in the CSV file

[image: The data in CSV file]

As you see, I intend to display 3 fields such as **ID**, **Username** and **Address** in 3 columns but all data is in a column.

Could you explain me that why I got 2 above messages and how can I display each field (ID, Username and Address) in each column?

Thanks in advance!

***P/S:*** Currently I am using Microsoft Excel 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV is an abreviation for Comma-separated Values.

```
 // Print header
stream << "ID\tUsername\tAddress";
```

You're using `TAB` characters to separate your columns. Try using commas instead.

EDIT: Also, you need to have a newline character `\n` at the end of each row.